# How do I send a request using the PATCH method for a Salesforce update?

Tags: java, playframework, salesforce

I'm using the Play framework to build a web app which integrates with Salesforce via their REST API.  In order to send an upsert command to their interface, it seems as if I must use the PATCH method instead of a POST method request.  Is it possible to use Play's WSRequest object and change the method type to PATCH instead of POST?  If not, how can I use a request object and send a PATCH request instead?

For learning purposes, what is the PATCH method and why does Salesforce enforce use of it instead of a POST method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about what is available in Play, but from the [REST API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm), here is a workaround if your library doesn't support PATCH:

> If you use an HTTP library that doesn't allow overriding or setting an
>   arbitrary HTTP method name, you can send a POST request and provide an
>   override to the HTTP method via the query string parameter
>   `_HttpMethod`.

For example, to update an Account, this will work with an actual POST request:

```
.../services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Account/0016000000eEhmxAAC?_HttpMethod=PATCH
```

As for the reasoning behind using PATCH, it is because PATCH is for partial updates to a resource. That is, you only have to send the fields you are updating. If you were required to send all the fields for a record in updates, PUT would probably be a better choice. POST is generally only for new inserts.  Here is an explanation with examples:
http://jasonsirota.com/rest-partial-updates-use-post-put-or-patch

Comment: No longer appears valid

Answer (score 1):

Play doesn't include a PATCH method in his WS library.

You could manually extend some classes from the framework in your app to add this method (mainly [these](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/WS.java) [two](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/ws/WSUrlFetch.java)), but I believe that the alternative provided by @ryanbrainard is a beter approach: use the _HttpMethod parameter in a POST to flag is as PATCH.