# how to send a http patch request with Lwp::Useragent?

Tags: perl, salesforce

I am working against the salesforce rest api with lwp::useragent.

I have to use the http patch request.

For get and post requests we get use the following code:

require LWP::UserAgent;

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $get_response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/',x=>'y');
my $post_response = $ua->post('http://search.cpan.org/',x=>'y');
```

Unfortunately this does not work

```
   my $patch_response = $ua->patch('http://search.cpan.org/',x=>'y');
```

I don't find how to do it with this module.

There is a workaround to this problem like explained here [How do I send a request using the PATCH method for a Salesforce update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799340/how-do-i-send-a-request-using-the-patch-method-for-a-salesforce-update#7803040)

This works but this is not a nice solution.

I saw that with python it is possible to make explicitly patch requests [How do I make a PATCH request in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853050/how-do-i-make-a-patch-request-in-python)  so i assume that there is also an option with perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(PATCH => $url);
... Add any necessary headers and body ...
my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has recently got a whole lot easier. `PATCH` is now implemented (like `POST`) in `HTTP::Message`.

First, update the `HTTP::Message` module (to 6.13 or later).

Then

```
my %fields = ( title => 'something', body => something else');

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request = HTTP::Request::Common::PATCH( $url, [ %fields ] );
my $response = $ua->request($request);
```